# qemu -cdrom ubuntu.iso -boot d -m 1024 -curses

Tags: syslinux, framebuffer

How do I disable frame buffers in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy kernel,
I tried all kinds of kernel parameters but none work?

```
DEFAULT ramdisk
LABEL ramdisk
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper toram initrd=/casper/initrd.img -- vesafb.nonsense=1
LABEL isotest
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.img -- vesafb.nonsense=1
LABEL memtest
  kernel /install/memtest
  append -
DISPLAY isolinux.txt
TIMEOUT 300
PROMPT 1
```

Comment: Why do you have a QEMU command in your title? It looks like you are trying to *enable* framebuffers rather than disabling them?

Comment: Because of the de -curses option I need a kernel dat stays in text mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
append boot=casper toram initrd=/casper/initrd.img nomodeset
```